# CSSParser объекты для описания аттрибутов, селекторов или классов

Tags: java, android, css

Стоит задача парсить css и использовать его для построения разметки. В результате я нашел парсер `CSS Parser` который построен на *org.w3c* и работает с ним. Парсинг выглядит следующим образом

```
   InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(s));
   CSSOMParser parser = new CSSOMParser(new SACParserCSS3());
   CSSStyleSheet sheet = parser.parseStyleSheet(source, null, null)
```

Из `CSSStyleSheet` есть возможность получить `CSSRulesList`, из которого, в свою очередь, можно получить правила в виде интерфейса `CSSRule` или их представление в виде строки. Мне же, для динамичной работы нужно вытаскивать селекторы, причем разделять где класс, а где идентификатор и иметь доступ к списку аттрибутов для каждого. Есть ли классы для описания CSS-класса или CSS-идентификатора и так далее? Дело в том, что по мере роста проекта css, будет видоизменяться и хотелось бы иметь возможность подходить более динимически к обработке `StyleSheet'а`

**UPDATE1**

Я прошу прощения, я до этого не имел дело с CSS вообще и поэтому могу оперировать не теми определениями.

Например есть CSS вида

```
.redtext {
   color:"#F00"
   font-size:15px
}
#green-back {
   background-color:"#0F0"
}
```

Писал от балды, поэтому могут быть ошибки - не суть. Здесь классом я называю `.redtext`, идентификатором `#green-back`, а селектором и то и другое по отдельности вместе со списком аттрибутов. И нужно мне разделить такой css на список "селекторов", чтобы у меня был доступ к названию, типу "селектора" и листу аттрибутов, пользуясь при этом встроенными средствами `CSSParser'a` или org.w3c - чтобы в дальнейшем, когда CSS будет видоизменяться мне не пришлось писать своих парсеров для каждого нового типа "селектора".

Возможно ли это, или нужно писать парсер самому?

Comment: если я правильно понимаю ,то `CSS-селектор` - это что-то вроде запроса к структуре элементов. `CSS-селекторы` ведь не прописаны в CSS. И вытаскивать их, соответственно неоткуда. Или я не правильно понимаю? Можете привести пример того, что вы называете `CSS-селектором`, и пытаетесь вытаскивать?

Comment: Добавил описание в теле вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Судя по документации вы можете вытаскивать селекторы из интерфейса [CSSRule](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSRule.html), точнее из его наследника [CSSStyleRule](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSStyleRule.html) методом [getSelectorText()](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSStyleRule.html#getSelectorText__), а атрибуты правила можно получить методом [getStyle()](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSStyleRule.html#getStyle__).

Единственное парсить строку селектора на отдельные селекторы видимо придется самому, так же как и определять тип селектора по первому символу, но это очень просто.

Comment: Понятно, что просто, но было бы круто от этого уйти, пользуясь встроенными возможностями. Что же, похоже пойду писать адаптер)